# How to increment MAC address?

Tags: c++, addition

I need to get the next valid MAC address from an initial one in C++.
So I tried to split the MAC address into separated hex integers, and increment one at a time, but I have no idea how to get the next when one of the split parts reach 0xFF.

How can I make that verification of the increment?

Any other ideas of how to increment a MAC address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the part is FF, change it to 00 and increment the next part. It's precisely the same way you increment a decimal number when a digit is a 9 -- you make it a 0 and increment the next digit to the left, so 19 becomes 20.